# In Google App Engine's Python DataStore model, is the result of get_by_key_name(<list_input>) in the same order as the input?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

The following code gets a list of entities in bulk by their key names:

> ```
> key_names = [a, b, c, d, e]
> result = models.SomeModel.get_by_key_name(key_names)
> ```

The question is:

Can we safely assume that the order of the entities in the returned list is always the same as the order of keys in the input list (key_names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Class Methods](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/modelclass#Class_Methods) (emphasis mine):

> Model.get_by_key_name (key_names, parent=None)
>
> ...
>
> If `key_names` consists of a single key name, this method returns the
>   model instance associated with the name if the name exists in the
>   Datastore, otherwise `None`. If `key_names` is a list, the return
>   value is **a corresponding list** of model instances, with `None`
>   values where no entity exists for a given key name.

I considered that a confirmation and I did make that assumption in my code  At least so far I didn't encounter any error or other hint/indication that the assumption would somehow be incorrect.